# Add a label with model using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I have two text input fields using ng-show to show/hide, is that possible to use a label along with the text box to display?

```
<label>Enter Min Value>
<input type="text" ng-model="minValue" ng-show="text1">
<label> Enter Max Value>
<input type="text" ng-model="maxValue" ng-show="text2">
```

When it is appearing it should appear textbox and label. Is that possible in angularjs?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You can wrap label and input in div and then show/hide that div itself.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Mayank Patel. can you pls provide me a link???

Comment: I will provide the fiddle in few mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<label ng-show="text1">Enter Min Value</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="minValue" ng-show="text1">
<label ng-show="text2"> Enter Max Value</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="maxValue" ng-show="text2">
```

Comment: Write some explanation for answer.

Comment: Thank you So much Mr. Shashikant Chauhan. it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, for your problem, you can wrap label and textbox into some HTML element, let's say `Div`.

Then, apply your required condition on that Div itself, like I did in the Fiddle below.

In that I have used 2 `Div`s with condition `ng-show="chkCondition=='text1'"` and `ng-show="chkCondition=='text2'"`.

So when the value of the `$scope.chkCondition` will be `'text1'`, label Enter Min Value and its textbox will appear and when the value of the `$scope.chkCondition` will be `'text2'`, label Enter Max Value and its textbox will appear.

I have removed the condition from the textbox and put it on the div.

Below is the fiddle link.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/g3u08zuv/6/)

Let me know in case this is not what you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-show="text1">
    <label>Enter Min Value>
    <input type="text" ng-model="minValue">
</div>
<div ng-show="text2">
    <label> Enter Max Value>
    <input type="text" ng-model="maxValue">
</div>
```